# Amazon Lambda invocation error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to call my Amazon Lambda function, from php, but I am getting strange rights error when I have AWSLambdaFullAccess rights.
My code:

```
$client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
'key' => 'AKI...G',
'secret' => 'VXD...YOse',
'region' => 'us-west-2'
));
$result = $client->invokeAsync(array(
'FunctionName' => 'arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:180...52:function:fe...st',
'InvokeArgs' => json_encode($array),
));
```

This is the error:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::69...67:user/developer is not authorized to 
perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: 
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:180...52:function:fe...st
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give your PHP code the permission to call your Lambda function (otherwise everybody will be able to call your code...).

You need to create a role with the right permission and make sure that your PHP code assumes that role (for examples with Cognito or EC2 roles).

The role should include something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1234567890",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:<YOUR-ACOUNT-ID>:function:<YOUR-FUNCTION-NAME>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where to put the json snippet?

Comment: This JSON snippet is what you need to put when you define the Role in the IAM permission. In the AWS Management console, you have the option to add permission to a Role, and you can paste this snippet there.